# I have slow mySQL queries causing very slow backend when we do changes or editing

Tags: magento2.3, database

this can be confirmed from the following snippet, showing slow queries that are taking almost 3 seconds to run:

```
| 1105858 | handyimp2_handydb | localhost | handyimp2_usrhand2 | Query | 3 | Creating sort index | SELECT DISTINCT `main_table`.* FROM `search_query` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_table.store_id IN (' |
| 1105860 | handyimp2_handydb | localhost | handyimp2_usrhand2 | Query | 2 | Creating sort index | SELECT DISTINCT `main_table`.* FROM `search_query` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_table.store_id IN (' |
| 1105861 | handyimp2_handydb | localhost | handyimp2_usrhand2 | Query | 1 | Creating sort index | SELECT DISTINCT `main_table`.* FROM `search_query` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_table.store_id IN (' |
| 1105862 | handyimp2_handydb | localhost | handyimp2_usrhand2 | Query | 1 | Creating sort index | SELECT DISTINCT `main_table`.* FROM `search_query` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_table.store_id IN (' |
| 1105863 | handyimp2_handydb | localhost | handyimp2_usrhand2 | Query | 1 | Creating sort index | SELECT DISTINCT `main_table`.* FROM `search_query` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_table.store_id IN (' |
| 1105864 | handyimp2_handydb | localhost | handyimp2_usrhand2 | Query | 3 | Sending data | SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM `search_query` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_table.store_id IN ('1')) A |
| 1105865 | handyimp2_handydb | localhost | handyimp2_usrhand2 | Query | 2 | Sending data | SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM `search_query` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_table.store_id IN (1)) AND |
| 1105866 | handyimp2_handydb | localhost | handyimp2_usrhand2 | Query | 1 | Sending data | SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM `search_query` AS `main_table` WHERE (main_tabl
```

Comment: this error is where coming?

Comment: Are you using Elasticsearch?

Comment: Yes we use Elasticsearch

Comment: Rather than a snippet, please post up to 100 lines from your Slow Query Log, please for analysis. And also post text results of SHOW CREATE TABLE `search_query`;